# Recommendation for the correct topology/architecture

Tags: 2010, architecture, extranet, topology

I've been tasked with proposing an architecture for our new SharePoint 2010 environment. The problem is that it will be hosted externally on a server that we have full control over at a data centre.

We have about 30 internal users and want to make use of single sign-on with our internal AD and will have about 1000 extranet users using forms based authentication.

Can anyone advise or suggest the best way to go with this?

Thanks,
James

Comment: That's hard to say. Please provide: expected usage of the site(s), what uptime do you expect (24/7?, or is downtime allowed?) What performance do you expect. Do you want to make use just of sharepoint foundation, or do you want to make use of a lot of different service applications like office web apps, (enterprise) search, user profile etc?

Comment: Usage by internal users will be continuous throughout the day. 24/7 would be preferable and will be SharePoint standard. Search at present is the only application that will be used. Someone has suggested an ADFS trust in passing?

Comment: ADFS Trust is possible, but it depends on the source of your extranet users: is it another company or, can it be, in theory, everyone?

Comment: Thank you Bas. Users will be the 30 internal users + some additional partner accounts which will also be in AD.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you review these:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21097

The amount of users will assist in determining storage, but concurrent users is more important for determining the initial scale that you require.  You may well be able to use a single server if it is 'beefy' enough.

SharePoint is scalable, so if you deploy it and later need to expand it, you can start scaling out servers to ease your bottlenecks.  So while it is important to size it correctly, it is not "critical" from a technical standpoint (although from a business one, it usually is).

Are you already licensed for this deployment?  Bear in mind you will technically need to hold licenses for those 1000 external users.

It is small enough you might benefit from a hosted solution like 365 or FPWeb.